# vertical-align <h2> in a <div>

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have the following code:

```
<div style="height: 120px; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(45, 144, 234); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); vertical-align: bottom;">
    <div style="vertical-align: bottom; height: 120px;">
        <h2 style="vertical-align: bottom; height: 120px;">text</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can't get the  text to the bottom of the nested divs. I can't use padding-top or margin-top as I occasionally have text wrapping.

Can someone advice me?

Comment: vertical-align does not to apply to DIV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:bottom;">Personal Information</div>
```

Comment: If you're using CSS Style sheets, you can apply it there...see: http://jsfiddle.net/johnk1/yYcsU/5/

Comment: Note: display:table-cell; is IE8+ support http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="height: 120px;">
    <div style="height: 120px;">
        <h2 style="position: absolute; bottom: 0">text</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

That should work.

It now doesn't matter how long the `h2` text is, it stays at the bottom of yout `div`.

Comment: And, as K Ivanoc states correctly: dump the vertical-alignments. They don't apply on you divs.